# No scroll on angular element in iPhone 5s

Tags: jquery, html, css, iphone, angularjs

I am embedding website into DOM element using AngularJS, Jquery, HTML5.See the code below:

```
digibin_app.directive("displayFile", function () {
        var updateElem = function (element) {
            return function (displayFile) {
                element.empty();

                var objectElem = {}

                if (displayFile && displayFile.type !== "") {
                    if (displayFile.type === "pdf") {
                        objectElem = angular.element(document.createElement("object"));
                        objectElem.attr("data", displayFile.fileUrl);
                        objectElem.attr("type", "application/pdf");
                    }
                    else if (displayFile.type === "html" ) {
                        objectElem = angular.element(document.createElement("object"));
                        var childHeight = parseInt(window.innerHeight); 

                        // problem is here in below line

                        objectElem.attr("style", "width:100%;height:"+childHeight+"px;margin:0px;"); 

                        objectElem.attr("data", displayFile.fileUrl);
                        objectElem.attr("type", "text/html");
                    }
                    else {
                        objectElem = angular.element(document.createElement("img"));
                        objectElem.attr("src", displayFile.fileUrl);
                    }
                }
                element.append(objectElem);
            };
        };

        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: {
                displayFile: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch("displayFile", updateElem(element));
            }
        };
    });
```

Everything is coming fine data,page rendering, there functionalities etc. Only thing which is bothering me is that for long pages it is not displaying scrollbars on IPHONE 5S. On Android its working absolutely fine.

### WHAT I TRIED:

1. I tried attaching touch event to element
2. Added css -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to body, elements parent container and even element too.

Kindly help me out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't show scrollbars? Those are usually hidden until you start scrolling. Can you still scroll?

Comment: @MathewBerg Nope. Still no scroll.